# Атака через форму обратной связи

Tags: безопасность, формы

На почту в папку спам пришли две пустые формы (по одной с каждой языковой версии сайта). Все поля - required. В почте появились только названия полей, указанные в файле php, причем поле selected пропало совершенно. Что это?! В чем может быть опасность? Что делать? Сайт работает, форма работает, но мне тревожно. Помогите)

Comment: *Все поля - required* ---  вот только required они на клиенте в браузере....Но кто сказал, что форму можно отправить только из браузера (или что там нельзя убрать эти атрибуты)?

Answer (score 1):

Обычное дело - спамеры работают.

Не хочешь спама - реализуй защиту от ботов. (только не капчи, это зло и ламерство)